# Image missing from distribution

Tags: ios

I am having an issue where an image is missing, but only when built for distribution.  Also, it only occurs on the iPhone 5, but not for the iPhone 4 or 4S.

[This](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39621/270956/8v0letf0bqvpkua/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Aug%2015,%202013%203.56.15%20PM.png) is a screenshot when built for development, on the simulator.

And [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39621/270941/cgydozb9e5ebu6g/upload.png) is a screenshot when built for distribution, on an actual iPhone 5.

I have a single target for both development and distribution.  Relevant code:

```
int deviceNumber = 4;
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 500)
            deviceNumber = 5;

MYIntroductionView *introductionView = [[MYIntroductionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height) panels:@[panel1,panel2,panel3]];

if(deviceNumber == 4){
            [introductionView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"One Degree_Iphone4_Background.png"]];
        }
        else{
            [introductionView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"One Degree_Iphone5_Background.png"]];
        }
```

And within MyIntroductionView.m, the relevant code is:

```
-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage{
    self.BackgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage;
}

-(void)buildBackgroundImage{
    self.BackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.BackgroundImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.BackgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    self.BackgroundImageView.autoresizesSubviews = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self addSubview:self.BackgroundImageView];
}
```

`buildBackgroundImage` is called within the init function.

Comment: Is this a single image or are these 3 images, for iPhone 3Gs (Non-Retina), iPhone 4/4s (Retina) and iPhone5 (Retina 568)? What about names of the files? You don't wrote it. Please add more info.

Comment: Are you sure it is not an issue related to iOS 7. I see from the device screenshot that is what you are running, try run on iPhone 5 with iOS 6.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc I added some code.

Comment: @sbarow Yes, I tried it with iOS 6 on an iPhone 5.  [same issue](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39621/270955/qi8iw1pd36wrn95/photo-5.PNG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is still the case but I know it used to be:

The iOS Simulator is not case-sensitive with regard to external filenames (such as your images). So if the image is named "myImage.png" and your program asks for "MyImage.png", the simulator *will correctly find and load the image*.

However when you try and run it on the device, it *is* case sensitive, and will not accept the incorrectly-cased file.

So double check that your capitalization of the file itself is identical to what you're asking for in your program. Hopefully that will fix your issue right up.